# How to insert contents into HTML page's iframe using HTMLUnit?

Tags: java, iframe, htmlunit

How can i insert some iframes inside a HTML page's iframe.

```
<HTML>
  <div id="data">
    <iframe height="160" width="600">
    </iframe>
  </div>
</HTML>
```

i could able to find the specific location using xpath

```
HtmlInlineFrame frame = (HtmlInlineFrame)page.getByXPath("//div[@id='data']/iframe").get(0);
```

i'm not clear how can i insert another htmlpage (iframe as htmlpage) inside this selected iframe. i have to insert more than one htmlpage (iframes as htmlpages) into this iframe Please suggest some way.

Comment: i refered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667352/htmlunit-and-xpath-domnode-getbyxpath-only-works-on-htmlpage) but didn't get solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
((HtmlInlineFrame)page1.getByXPath("//div[@id='data']/iframe").get(0)).setTextContent(page2.asXml());
```

this will work, still there is a problem that, there is a parser working in between, that is content set as

```
page2.asXml();
```

will set the content. After that when viewing the page as xml all '<' replaced with `&lt;` and '>' replaced with `&gt;`

```
((HtmlInlineFrame)page1.getByXPath("//div[@id='data']/iframe").get(0)).appendChild(page2);
```

will fix earlier issue still it will add two unwanted lines

Comment: Setting text content seems pretty efficient :-). You can use "page.getFrameByName(name)" to get frame, in case the "id" attributes is liable to change and that removes the need for the cast.